# How to use Robotics Middleware Framework (Open-RMF) with a commercial robots?

Tags: ros2, mobile-robot

I have a commercial robots (the Reeman robot) and it doesnt have a Fleet Management System (FMS). So would like to use the Robotics Middleware Framework (Open-RMF) for developing own FMS. So , I'm new in the FMS and would like to ask some questions here so can hit the ground. So far my understanding I will need the password and username of the CPU of the robot so can start developing the FMS, correct? Another question is Do I have to know the robots API so can communicate with the Open-RMF or the Open-RMF itself provide it? What other things need it to hit the ground?

Thanks